# c# how can i change the values of the original list when i process the list which extracted from the original list using List.Where

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list contains many Blocks, and the Blocks are divided into old ones and new ones, using a property 'IsOld' in class 'Block' to specify them. Now I extract the old ones like this:

```
List<Block> olds = blocks.Where(item => {return item.IsOld;}).ToList();
```

and after I change some values of the properties on the items in 'olds' list, the corresponding ones in the original list 'blocks' do not change. And I don't know how to deal with it. And that means if I use List.Where method, it will make a deep copy for every item?

---

'Block' is a struct and I first thought it was a class.
so sorry to trouble you because of my careless o(︶︿︶)o

Comment: The code you've posted won't compile, to start with - `Where` doesn't return a `List<T>`. No, `Where` does *not* create a deep copy, although if `Block` is a struct it will be creating a value copy. It would really help if you could provide a short but complete program which compiles and runs, demonstrating the problem.

Comment: `Block` type is a *class* or *struct*?

Comment: @Dennis Block is a class, and will it be different if it is a struct?

Comment: @Ggicci: That still wouldn't compile, as it's `ToList`, not `toList`. That means twice, you've given us code which isn't the real code. *Please* post some real code demonstrating the problem, rather than keeping us guessing.

Comment: @Ggicci: yes, there will be different behavior for structs. We're all waiting for you *real* code. :) Besides, you can write shorter: `blocks.Where(item => item.IsOld).ToList()`

Comment: @Dennis I'm sorry, I defined 'Block' as a struct, it's a mistake and I know what's wrong with my problem after reading Maarten's post. Thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying that you are changing values of **properties**, and not replacing the objects themselves. Therefore the original objects in the blocks list should also be updated, that is if Block is defined as a class-type. If Block is a struct, than every assignment is done in a copy of the original object, and then your changes in the olds list should not be reflected in the original blocks list.

Is Block a struct?

Comment: yes, it's a struct. and I know what's wrong, thank you all :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the properties of the "old" items, why not just do:

```
blocks.ForEach(item => 
{
    if (item.IsOld)
    {
        // Do your changes here ...
    }
});
```

Comment: But I want to sort the 'olds' list in a specified order and then to do some changes...

Answer (score 1):

instead of what you are doing, try this :

`blocks.ForEach(item => { if(item.IsOld){/*perform change here*/} });`

Also, if you want to see where you are going wrong, paste your code where you are changing, it would be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Since block is a struct, you could do this:

```
List<Block> updatedBlocks = blocks
    .Select(item => item.IsOld ? new Block { X=item.X, Y=item.Y, Z=updatedZ } : item)
    .ToList();
```

More readably, define a method

```
private Block UpdateBlock(Block sourceValue)
{
    if (!sourceValue.IsOld)
        return sourceValue;

    var result = new Block // ...
    // populate result here...
    return result;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
List<Block> updatedBlocks = blocks.Select(UpdateBlock).ToList();
```